# SQL equivalent of IN operator that acts as AND instead of OR?

Tags: sql, inner-join, 3nf

Rather than describe, I'll simply show what I'm trying to do. 3 tables in 3NF. product_badges is the join table. (The exists sub-query is necessary.)

```
SELECT * FROM shop_products WHERE EXISTS ( // this line cannot change
    SELECT * FROM product_badges as pb 
    WHERE pb.product_id=shop_products.id
    AND pb.badge_id IN (1,2,3,4)
);
```

Now this will return all the products that have a badge_id of 1 OR 2 OR 3 OR 4. What I want is to **get only the products that meet ALL those values**. I tried to do pb.badge_id=1 AND pb.badge_id=2 etc but this returns nothing -- which makes sense to me now. I also tried doing multiple queries with an INTERSECT but that resulted in an error. I'm guessing multiple queries is the key but UNION is basically the same as IN and I'm not certain how to use a JOIN in this case.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense for the column to match all of the values.  A record can have multiple columns, but, the column can only have one value.

Comment: You are looking for the relational division operator (which doesn't exist) but you can use one of [the methods here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Comment: @Ek0nomik - that column is part of a many-to-many join table linking multiple attributes to multiple products. Think of it as searching for pants but instead of returning all the pants I only want pants with pockets and cargo pockets and a button fly. The badge_id correlates to each of those attributes

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks for link. Looks like it's exactly what the other post is talking about. Good chance to understand better what's going on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following (assuming exactly 4 different required bagde_id's):

```
SELECT * FROM shop_products WHERE EXISTS ( // this line cannot change
    SELECT pb.product_id, count(distinct pb.bagde_id) FROM product_badges as pb 
    WHERE pb.product_id=shop_products.id
    AND pb.badge_id IN (1,2,3,4)
    GROUP BY pb.product_id
    HAVING count(distinct pb.bagde_id) = 4
);
```