# SQL select one row from table 1 joining on multiple rows in table 2

Tags: mysql, join, sql

So I have two tables, the first would be users_

```
Name
------
Carol
Sue
```

and the second would be interests_

```
Name        Interest
----------------------
Carol       Books
Carol       Dancing
Carol       Sports    
Sue         Books
Sue         Dancing
```

The user will be presented with checkboxes to select a match based on criteria for similar interests like this

[image]

So if the user selected Books and Dancing as interests for their match, what type of sql query would I build to combine multiple rows in interests and ensure that the result is Sue, since she had Books and Dancing as interests but NOT Sports?

any help will go a long way thanks!

Comment: WHERE Interest IN('Books', 'Dancing'...etc).

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.  I understand that you want to join users to interests, but what are you filtering on and what columns do you want?

Comment: @JohnRuddell that would return both Carol and Sue

Comment: @JohnRuddell Think of a dating website, you want to find match(es) who is interested in things you are interested in exactly, so the result should return people who fit that criteria, in this case you're looking for someone who like books and dancing exactly

Comment: @Lamak i realized that and wrote an appropriate answer if you would like to see it

Comment: Hmmmm... this reminds me of a job interview question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simple way to do it

```
select
i.name 
from interests i
where i.interest in ('Books','Dancing')
and not exists
(
  select 1 from interests i1
  where interest not in ('Books','Dancing')
  AND i.name = i1.name
)
group by i.name
having count(*) = 2
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/08e54/1)**

Comment: hmm @JohnRuddell you are right it does not need having clause.

Comment: Yea the having will just slow it down.. grouping by name should be sufficient :) regardless +1 for another way to do it

Comment: This example worked, when I added in more users of with the same 2 interests it returned all correct matches, thanks Abhik!

Answer (score 2):

so basically to do this build a negative list of users that have more than those two and then select the others

```
SELECT u.name 
FROM users_ u     
JOIN interests_ i ON i.name = u.name
JOIN
(   SELECT u.name 
    FROM users_ u
    JOIN interests_ i ON i.name = u.name
    WHERE i.interest NOT IN('Books', 'Dancing')
) t
WHERE u.name <> t.name 
  AND i.interest IN('Books', 'Dancing')
GROUP BY u.name
HAVING COUNT(u.name) = 2;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15393/5)

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this result:

```
SELECT u.name
  FROM users_ u
  JOIN interests_ n01 ON n01.name = u.name AND n01.interest = 'Books'
  JOIN interests_ n02 ON n02.name = u.name AND n02.interest = 'Dancing'
  LEFT JOIN interests_ x01 ON x01.name = u.name AND x01.interest = 'Sports'
  LEFT JOIN interests_ x02 ON x02.name = u.name AND x01.interest = 'Wine'
 WHERE x01.name IS NULL
   AND x02.name IS NULL
```

This approach requires a JOIN for each interest to be "included", and an anti-join to each interest to be "excluded". This approach is flexible, but can become unwieldy for a large number of interests.

To look for matches for ONLY the specified interests, without having to list out all the interests not to match, we could use an anti-join to find rows in interests that don't match:

```
SELECT u.name
  FROM users_ u
  JOIN interests_ n01 ON n01.name = u.name AND n01.interest = 'Books'
  JOIN interests_ n02 ON n02.name = u.name AND n02.interest = 'Dancing'
  LEFT
  JOIN interests_ o 
    ON o.name = u.name
   AND o.interest NOT IN ('Books','Dancing')
 WHERE o.name IS NULL
```

Another approach would be to make use of JOIN operations and a `COUNT()` aggregate, e.g.

```
SELECT u.name
  FROM users_ u
  JOIN interests_ n 
    ON n.name = u.name 
   AND n.interest IN ('Books','Dancing')
  LEFT
  JOIN interests_ o
    ON o.name = u.name
   AND o.interest NOT IN ('Books','Dancing')
 WHERE o.name IS NULL
 GROUP BY u.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT n.interest) = 2
```

There are some other approaches (these are just some examples).

Comment: @JohnRuddell: In the last query, the purpose of the `HAVING COUNT` is to verify that we "matched" _both_ rows `'Books'` and `'Dancing'`, and not just  a subset of that. (If we didn't have that, then the query would return, for example, users that matched on `'Books'` but didn't match on `'Dancing'`.) The `DISTINCT` keyword is thrown in because we weren't explicitly given a constraint that `(name,interest)` will be unique.

Comment: Ok.. I was just curious because it returned the same result either way.

Comment: @John Ruddell: consider extending the example to include user `Miranda` that has one interest: `Dancing`. Without the `HAVING COUNT()` the query would return user `Miranda`, because there was a matching row. We'd omit that clause if we wanted all users that matched at least one of the specified interests, but not necessarily ALL of them. (We need to extend the sample data to demonstrate the difference.)

Comment: Yea I got that when you explained it :)

Answer (score 0):

Make it use of SQL `in` operator

```
select * from  interests_ where Interest in ('Books', 'Dancing') and Interest not in ('Sports');
```

EDIT 1

This worked for me

```
SELECT * FROM user_ WHERE EXISTS ( 
    SELECT i.Name, count(distinct i.Interest) FROM interests_ as i
    WHERE i.Name=user_.Name
    AND i.Interest IN ('Books','Dancing')
    GROUP BY i.Name
    HAVING count(distinct i.Interest) = 2
);
```

REF : [SQL equivalent of IN operator that acts as AND instead of OR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585967/sql-equivalent-of-in-operator-that-acts-as-and-instead-of-or)

Comment: This doesn't take into account the requirement that "the result is Sue, since she had Books and Dancing as interests but NOT Sports"

Comment: There could be multiple matches actually! just want to make sure that the criteria is met, so could I remove "and Interest not in ('Sports')" ?

Comment: No, it doesn't, it's too specific. With your query, if the user only has Books as interest, it will still return that user

Comment: imagine all you have to work with is 'Books' and 'Dancing' and go from there... not in 'Sports' is a bad idea

Comment: @NavasBasheer if you post a way to do it appropriately i'll remove my downvote :) or if you delete your post

Comment: @JohnRuddell, Yeah :D almost similar answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585967/sql-equivalent-of-in-operator-that-acts-as-and-instead-of-or, digg on it, join me !!!

Answer (score -1):

Left Joins can be very useful. You could try this.

```
SELECT users_.*
FROM users_
    LEFT JOIN interests_
    ON users_.Name = Interests_.Name
            WHERE interests_.Interests = 'Books'
            AND interests_.Interests = 'Dancing'
```

Comment: this doesnt work. and you should look into using an alias for your tables... better SQL practice

Comment: Yes, a LEFT JOIN is very useful. But the query posted here will return all rows from `users_`, and some rows from `users_` will be repeated (e.g. 'Sue' and 'Carol'.) While this might be an interesting resultset, it doesn't meet the requirements that were specified.